# SELECT takes 100ms; CREATE table as select - or - INSERT into select take 15mins

Tags: oracle

I have a very simple `SELECT *` query with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM "BMAN_TP3"."TT_SPLDR_55E63A28_59358" SELECT_TABLE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM "BMAN_TP3"."USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES" EXISTS_TABLE
                  WHERE "SELECT_TABLE"."UDA_NAME" = "EXISTS_TABLE"."UDA_NAME")
```

This query about 100 ms to execute and fetch < 2000 records.

If this query is nested in a `CREATE TABLE AS` or in a `INSERT INTO` it runs in **15 minutes**.

```
CREATE TABLE BMAN_TP3.TT_UDA_TEST TABLESPACE BMAN_TP3_U AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM "BMAN_TP3"."TT_SPLDR_55E63A28_59358" SELECT_TABLE
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM "BMAN_TP3"."USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES" EXISTS_TABLE
                    WHERE "SELECT_TABLE"."UDA_NAME" = "EXISTS_TABLE"."UDA_NAME")
)
```

I have a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `UDA_NAME` field of both `USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES` (alternate-key) and `TT_SPLDR_55E63A28_59358` tables.

If I remove the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` it takes half a second.

---

**EDIT :**

If I use

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "BMAN_TP3"."USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES"
ON "SELECT_TABLE"."UDA_NAME" = "USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES"."UDA_NAME"
WHERE "USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES"."UDA_NAME" IS NULL
```

instead of the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` it runs in half a second.

I cannot explain why `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is so slow!

---

**EXPLAIN for CREATE TABLE AS with WHERE NOT EXISTS :** (15 mins)

[image]

**EXPLAIN for CREATE TABLE AS with LEFT OUTER JOIN :** (500 ms)

[image]

---

**EXPLAIN for SELECT only with WHERE NOT EXISTS :** (100ms)

[image]

**EXPLAIN for SELECT only with LEFT OUTER JOIN :** (100ms)

[image]

It seems that when selecting it makes the same operations, but when creating the table it does different operations for `WHERE NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: What does [`EXPLAIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm) say?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid See my post above

Comment: Please add the explain plan for the LEFT OUTER JOIN case.  Thanks.

Comment: Also note that your WHERE NOT EXISTS and LEFT OUTER JOIN queries are not performing the same operations.  The WNE is excluding entries that are not being excluded by the LOJ.  To have the LOJ perform the same work it would need to be `LEFT OUTER JOIN BMAN_TP3.USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES UDA ON SELECT_TABLE.UDA_NAME = UDA.UDA_NAME WHERE UDA.UDA_NAME IS NULL`.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis Sorry, I cutted the `WHERE "USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES"."UDA_NAME" IS NULL` part in the question. Actually, it was already in my query. Fixed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

It's the alternate-key on `UDA_NAME` for table `USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES`.

If I disable it and I create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the same field, it runs in 500 millis.

Anyway, I'm not sure about the reason of this behavior.